# VS 2010 and Entity Framework: accessing SQL Server 2000 databases

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2000

Consider a Visual Studio 2010 project whose requirement is to model the data using Entity Framework. The datasource is a SQL Server 2000 database.

The first step is creating a new ADO.NET Entity Data Model item.

The Entity Data Model Wizard prompts for a Data Connection.

[image]

When creating a new Connection, you will need to use a provider other than `SqlClient`. Usually it's `SQLOLEDB`.

The list of data providers only has `SqlClient` or ".NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server".

[image]

- Is there a work-around for Visual Studio 2010 to create or use data connections to SQL Server 2000 using the Entity Framework?

Comment: Hey, isn't that nice! A downvote on a question 1.5 years old. Care to comment why, mysterious downvoter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, SQL Server 2000 isn't supported.

[Entity Framework v2](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=499186&wa=wsignin1.0)

Answer (score 3):

We were able to use EF with sql 2000 by setting up the initial context in vs2005, then doing an upgrade to vs 2010. Terrible, but worked.

**UPDATE:**

I decided to write a how-to for anyone else needing to do this. We haven't seen any side effects yet, and allows the use of the VS 2010 designer.

[How To Use Entity Framework 4 With Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2000](http://www.skonet.com/Articles_Archive/How_To_Use_Entity_Framework_4_With_Visual_Studio_2010_and_SQL_Server_2000.aspx)

Comment: Does anyonw know here I can find the link above, if it exists? The link is broken and we're having this issue right now.

Comment: Sorry, had to migrate off my server so my site is down right now. In short, need to generate a more recent *.edmx file, then update the references to "2005/8/12" to be "2000". I think there were some other changes, but that was the jist of it. Hopefully that helps.