# EntityFramework SQL Server 2000?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Entity Framework v2 doesn't support sql 2000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600630/entity-framework-v2-doesnt-support-sql-2000)

I have a windows forms application that access a SQL Server 2000 server.  Originally this application was written with Visual Studio 2008.  Since then we have migrated to Visual Studio 2010 and when I try to add new entities to the .edmx (using Update Model from Database) I get a message saying that EntityFramwork only works with SQL Server 2005 or greater.

Did something change in VS2010? I was definitely able to add entities before.

Comment: SQL Server 2000 is just simply **way too old** to be supported anymore - you need to upgrade!

Comment: Its the only database still in 2000 because a really old app still needs it, guess I'm just screwed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework v2 doesn't support sql 2000?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600630/entity-framework-v2-doesnt-support-sql-2000) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829890/vs-2010-and-entity-framework-accessing-sql-server-2000-databases

Comment: With SQL Server 2000 - yes, you're screwed...

Comment: A really old app still needs it to be in 2000? What compatibility was broken in 2005 or 2008 that the old app won't support?

Comment: No doubt a case of someone deciding that "it ain't broke", so "don't fix it". Hint: if it's still running on SQL Server 2000, then it's badly "broke".

Answer (score 7):

EF4's support for SQL Server 2000 is spotty; things like `First` and `FirstOrDefault` (or any functions that result in a `TOP` expression) will not work, for example. While the runtime *may* generate code that is compatible, the designer is no longer compatible with anything older than SQL Server 2005.

Unfortunately, that's what you're stuck with. Your best option (in the short term) would probably be to mirror a copy of your database in a SQL Server 2005 Express instance and point the designer to that.

While I realize that companies can have a significant investment in software and upgrading is not always feasible, SQL Server 2000 is 11 -- almost 12 -- years old, and it's not really reasonable to expect cutting-edge tools to support technology this old when multiple versions have been released since then.

Good luck!