# Entity Framework migrations on legacy database

Tags: entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

We have several legacy SQL Server databases that we occasionally make schema changes to. We currently have a utility written in C++ that allows users to update their DB's with these schema changes. The utility currently generates dynamic sql to create all DB objects. I am looking into redoing this and thought EF migrations might be a good way to go. I have read up a bit on the subject and I have a general idea of how it works. But I'm having a bit of a hard time figuring out how I would set it up to replace our current procedure (or if it is even possible). Currently, a client could be on any one of a number of previous versions. I'm assuming I would have to go back to the oldest possible version and create my model/initial migration from that, then generate incremental migrations for each version change in order to support updates from all versions. Is that a correct assumption? Also, currently our clients could be using sql server 2000, 2005, or 2008. Would this have any effect on how I would set things up (or if I even could)? Further, the goal is to create a utility with a (C# - probably WPF) UI that the user can use to manipulate the migrations (up or down, preferably). I've seen a lot of examples of how to manipulate migrations from command-line within package manager but not a lot of stuff on how to create a utility with a friendly UI for upgrading/downgrading DB's in production. Also, I have not seen anything that shows how to create stored procedures in a migration (our DBs rely on some stored procedures). I'm assuming that, if nothing else, I can use the Sql() method to generate a SQL query to create a SP. Is that correct? Is there a better way?

I know my questions are a bit non-specific and I apologize for that. But I'm still in the beginning processes of learning this and I'd like to get an idea of whether or not this is a good way to go. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Dennis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, on SQL Server support, Entity Framework doesn't really support SQL Server 2000. See this question:
[EntityFramework SQL Server 2000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614748/entityframework-sql-server-2000)

On the question of supporting all the multiple versions, you have the right idea about needing to generate an initial migration for the oldest version first then incrementally altering the model and generating migrations to support the later versions. This will be a pain as the migrations are opinionated about how they represent the model in the database and you will be doing a lot of messing about to end up with a model and a set of migrations that fully represent that. Specific concerns are indexes, column lengths, data types, stored procedures, triggers, functions, partitioning.

The `Sql()` function gets you around most issues, though also helpful in the migrations are functions like `CreateIndex` and `AlterColumn`.

For automating this, the migrations are definitely available as powershell cmdlets which are themselves just .Net objects so can be called programmatically.

As this question is a year old, I assume you will have made a decision on whether to do this. My opinion is that it is hard to see that it's worth the effort. If you were re-platforming the code base that uses this database to Entity Framework then it would make sense. Otherwise there are bound to be better tools out there for database version management. My first port of call would be Redgate.